# BitBuket auto pull using Cron Job

Tags: git, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, cron, bitbucket

I was trying to create CronJob to `git pull` every minute to keep my QA environment up-to-date.

the git pull needs to be done by the system user. In the .git repository, i did configure remote origin with username and password.

```
https://{username}:{password}@bitbucket.org/{projectname}/project.git
```

In Cornjob I did write the below code to run every minute.

```
*/1 * * * * su -s /bin/sh nobody -c 'cd /var/www/project && /usr/bin/git pull -q  origin branchname'
```

After execution, it's showing the below error.

```
error: insufficient permission for adding an object to repository database .git/objects
fatal: failed to write object
fatal: unpack-objects failed
```

Can somebody help me out?

Answer (score 1):

User `nobody` doesn't have access to `/var/www/project`. Run the command under a user that has. Or give user `nobody` necessary rights.

Or better yet, configure a web hook at bitbucket that will notify you about changes; that way you don't need to poll bitbucket at all.

Comment: I've upvoted because this is the right answer, but I wish I could upvote again because that second part is the right question.

Comment: given user nobody necessary rights. it's working now. thanks, phd.